# Update Matplotlib Chart on Dynamically updating DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have an empty dataframe and I am appending one data at a time to it. Like this:

```
# Initialize an empty dataframe to store the tweet id and sentiment
tweets = pd.DataFrame(columns=['tweet_id', 'sentiment'])
```

`tweet_id` is an integer, `sentiment` is a string which can have 3 values viz. "Positive", "Negative", "Neutral". Now I have a loop which appends to the dataframe:

```
for i in range(len(whatever_I_want)):
    tweet = get_new_tweet()
    tweets = tweets.append({'tweet_id': tweet['id'], 'sentiment': tweet['sentiment']}, ignore_index=True)
    # Update the plot with the new dataframe
    tweets.groupby('sentiment').count()['tweet_id'].plot.bar()
    plt.show()
```

This is working but it is creating multiple plots and I need to close one in order to view another. I want the same plot to update whenever I run the loop. How should I do this? I searched for it, and I got solutions which are either using numpy to append or showing line charts.

How do I achieve this by using pandas `groupby()`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that `tweets.groupby('sentiment').count()['tweet_id'].plot.bar()` will be able to update your plot without generating a new one because it returns a `matplotlib.axes.Axes` object (documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)).

You could instead pass the `index` and `values` of `tweets.groupby('sentiment').count()['tweet_id'])` to `plt.bar`:

```
 for i in range(len(whatever_I_want)):
    tweet = get_new_tweet()
    tweets = tweets.append({'tweet_id': tweet['id'], 'sentiment': tweet['sentiment']}, ignore_index=True)
    # Update the plot with the new dataframe
    grouped_tweets = tweets.groupby('sentiment').count()['tweet_id']
    plt.bar(x=grouped_tweets.index, height=grouped_tweets.values)
 plt.show()
```

Comment: Since `plt.show()` is inside the loop, it still generates a lot of plots.

Comment: @KumarPriyansh oh my mistake, i moved it to outside the loop so hopefully that resolves the issue

Comment: Problem is, the plot will only show once the loop is completed and in my case the loop is infinite. It will never reach `plt.show()` - so as per the original question, the plot update must be inside the loop and the plot must be updated on every iteration only.

Comment: @KumarPriyansh I see... you may have more success using matplotlib animation API in that case

Comment: Would you please update your code as per the animation API?